# Pointer to pointer not work

Tags: c++, pointers

In my code I am trying to make loop that works by changing pointer target and printing value of the same pointer. This code is my method for infinite list.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class pacjent
{
public:
    char nazwisko[20];
    pacjent*nastepny;
    pacjent();
    ~pacjent();
};

pacjent *POCZATEK = NULL, *KONIEC = NULL;

pacjent::pacjent() {
    cout << "Podaj nazwisko: ";
    cin >> nazwisko;
    if (POCZATEK == NULL) {
        POCZATEK = this;
        KONIEC = this;
    } else {
        KONIEC->nastepny = this;
        nastepny = NULL;
    }
}

pacjent::~pacjent() {
    POCZATEK = POCZATEK->nastepny;
}

pacjent* NOW = POCZATEK;
void drukuj() {
    /////////////////////////////////  LOOP MENTIONED
    // while(NOW->nastepny!=NULL)
    // {
    cout << NOW->nazwisko << endl; //do not work
    //     NOW=NOW->nastepny;
    //  cout << POCZATEK->nazwisko << endl; // works fine
    // }
} //////////////////////////////////


int main() {
    char SELECTOR;
    while (SELECTOR != 'q') {
        cin >> SELECTOR;
        switch (SELECTOR) {
        case 'n':
            KONIEC = new pacjent;
            break;
        case 'p':
            delete POCZATEK;
            break;
        case 'd':
            drukuj();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function `drukuj()` won't print content of 'NOW' (I get empty screen) pointer but with `POCZATEK` works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You never update `NOW`...

Comment: `NOW` is not a pointer to a pointer.  I don't see any pointers to pointers anywhere.

Comment: How wrong can it get - sorry - your code is junk - get some books!

Comment: Not knowing basic C++        .

Comment: The variable names are horrible.

Comment: Only because they are named in Polish or because some of them are UPPERCASED?

Comment: Polish is fine (although I would suggest English) - uppercase looks like an ugly preprocessor macro

Answer (score 1):

> The function drukuj() won't print content of 'NOW' (I get empty screen) pointer but with POCZATEK works fine. Any ideas?

`NOW` is initialized as:

```
pacjent* NOW = POCZATEK;
```

At that time, the value of `POCZATEK` is `NULL`. Hence, `NOW` also gets initialized to `NULL`. Later on in your code, `POCZATEK` is changed to point to newly created objects but that does not change where `NOW` points to. It still points to `NULL`.

You can make sure `NOW` and `POCZATEK` always point to the same object by making `NOW` a reference to a pointer and initialize it with `POCZATEK`.

```
pacjent*& NOW = POCZATEK;
```

Comment: Is there any method to set NOW as always poinitng to POCZATEK?

Answer (score 0):

```
pacjent* NOW = POCZATEK; // this is null
```

Create new pacjent object and assign it's members the values you want then try to print out.